In Keycloak, How to revoke the previous token automatically, when we generate the new token in spring boot?
When we generate new keycloak (V-24) token it's working fine but the previous token is also working, so we want to expire the previous token.
We tried to logout before login.
And also we have added a flow for User session count limiter from keycloak admin UI.

Can you be more specific about what token you are generating? (Keycloak supports many different kinds of token and different ways of generating them).

I'm generateing access token

A JWT is immutable and cannot be invalidated.
What can be revoked are sessions (there are one on the authorization server and other ones on each of the clients with oauth2Login), but a JWT decoder running inside a resource server has no mean to know what happened to clients and authorization server sessions.
The fact that you can't revoke a JWT access token is one of the reasons why JWTs should not leave the servers you trust. If you want to keep control on user session, access JWTs must not be sent to single-page or mobile applications. When you close sessions on your servers, the tokens stored in this sessions will be deleted.

You can revoke access tokens using https://www.keycloak.org/docs/22.0.1/securing_apps/#_token_revocation_endpoint

Revoking is not invalidating. Revoking an access token (JWT or not) can have an influence only when introspecting it on the authorization server. A JWT decoder will keep considering it valid until its expiration. As a side note, introspection is inefficient (introduces the latency of a call to the authorization server for each request) and it doesn't scale (if the number of requests and resource servers grows, the authorization server can be flooded with these introspection requests).

yes, that is true for offline checks, but for online checks you would be able to check that the token was blacklisted. Yes, you are correct regarding the performance, but there are use-cases that it can be desirable to perform always the check online just to be on the safe side, for example in highly privilege critical operations.
Although, all you said is correct, I feel that mentioned the online verification is a valid argument if one is willing to make the trade off.

I can't agree with the “highly privilege critical operations" scenario. If you follow the current recommendations and keep tokens in session on the backend, tokens are deleted when sessions are revoked. And if Back-Channel Logout is correctly configured, OAuth2 client sessions are revoked as soon as authorization server one is revoked. So there is no good reason for compromising efficiency.

And anyway, introspecting a JWT is a waste of resources. If you intend to use introspection, just use shorter opaque tokens, it will save some computing on the authorization server and some network resources.

Yes, theoretically you are correct, one applies the BFF and some of this problems are solved, but in legacy system you have so many constraints that sometimes you need to compromised at least on my experience. Yes, ideally, you have a short living token, but there it is also a compromise between security, and performance, the shorter it is the least performance it will be.
